# how to use connection string & it shows unrecognized escape sequence?

Tags: c#, connection

```
stringConnectionString = "Data Source = 192.168.0.222; Initial Catalog= ;User ID=xxxxxxx;Password=yyyyyy";
```

this is my connectionstring i don't know how to assign connection string & this is my file location

> D:\Gurusoft\Gowtham\work\G9HCMS\G9Collaboration\DataProvider\clsPatients.cs

my entire code

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string stringConnectionString = null;           
        DataSet objDataSet;
        SqlCommand objSqlCommand;


        try
        {
            int intNum = 0;
            objDataSet = new DataSet();
            objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            stringConnectionString = (@"Data Source = 192.xxx.0.yyy; Initial Catalog=C:User\G9HCMS\clsPatients.cs;Persist Security Info=true;User ID=xxxx;Password=yyyyy");
            SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(stringConnectionString);

            {

                if (objSqlConnection != null)
                {
                    objSqlConnection.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter objSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from MR_Patients", objSqlConnection);
                    // objSqlCommand.Connection = objSqlConnection;                                                                
                    objSqlDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);

                    for (intNum = 0; intNum <= objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; intNum++)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[1].ItemArray[1].ToString());

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    objSqlConnection.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("connection Error");

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception" + objException.ToString());


        }
    }
}
```

}

how to set this connection string

Comment: I assume you are trying to assign this connection string to a variable and your code is in that particular file? You might consider sharing the code you are writing. Also, I am not sure if you obfuscated the username and password, but in the future be careful not to include them.

Comment: don't worry both are wrong

Comment: could you provide some more context & your code so we understand what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @ before connection string

```
new SQlConnection(@"Data Source=HOGAR\SQLEXPRES;Init...");
```

Or use \ instead of \

```
new SQlConnection("Data Source=HOGAR\\SQLEXPRES;Init...");
```

Comment: SqlConnection("Data Source = 192.xxx.0.yyy; Initial Catalog=C:User\\G9HCMS\\clsPatients.cs;Persist Security Info=true;User ID=xxxx;Password=yyyyy");            This line of code is working for me check this one